# Reading a block of bytes from one file and writing to other until all blocks are read?

Tags: java, file, file-io, inputstream, fileoutputstream

I am working a project in which I have to play with some file reading writing tasks. I have to read 8 bytes from a file at one time and perform some operations on that block and then write that block to second file, then repeat the cycle until first file is completely read in chuncks of 8 bytes everytime and the after manipulation the data should be added/appended to the second. However, in doing so, I am facing some problems. Following is what I am trying:

```
private File readFromFile1(File file1) {

    int offset = 0;
    long message= 0;

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
        byte[] data = new byte[8];
        file2 = new File("file2.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file2.getAbsolutePath(), true);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

        while(fis.read(data, offset, 8) != -1)
        {
            message = someOperation(data); // operation according to business logic
            dos.writeLong(message);
        }
        fos.close();
        dos.close();
        fis.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Some error occurred while reading from File:" + e);
    }
    return file2;
}
```

I am not getting the desired output this way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your offset is never incremented or it's done in your someOperation method ?

Comment: You must check the return value of fis.read() to know the actual amount of bytes read. And also, I don't see a definition for file2. And like Julien said, no offset increment...

Comment: I assumed that decryptedFile and file2 where the same, don't you think @CPUTerminator ?

Comment: @Julien Yeah... Seems like a big leap though 'decryptedFile' to 'file2'

Comment: Change your while loop to `while((readcnt = fis.read(data)) > 0)` and you will never have to worry about the offset anyway, and you'll have the variable readcnt to keep track of how many bytes you've read

Comment: @julian and CPU T ... that's a typo. it's file 2. I have corrected it as well. yes I this the way I am using offset. Not incrementing.

Comment: And whats with 'byte [] decryptedBytes = new byte [8];' Its not being used...

Comment: that i tried to use to try out, but did not work out, Code has become a  mess trying this out. problem is just reading a block of 8 bytes from file1 and after some operation write that to file2, hence returning file2.

Comment: Change it to use `DataInputStream.readFully(data).` Then you'll be sure you actually have 8 bytes each time. What's supposed to happen if the file isn't a multiple of 8 bytes long?

Comment: @Julien He doesn't have to increment the offset. It can be zero throughout, and it usually is. You don't appear to understand how the read() API works.

Comment: @EJP maybe i don't have the javadoc enough in mind :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the following, it uses `NIO` and especially the `ByteBuffer` class for the `long` handling. You can of course implement it the standard java way, but since i am a `NIO` fan, here is a possible solution.

The major problem in your code is that `while(fis.read(data, offset, 8) != -1)` will read **up to** 8 bytes, and not always 8 bytes, plus reading in such small portions is not very efficient.

I have put some comments in my code, if something is unclear please leave a comment. My `someOperation(...)` function just copies the next `long` value from the buffer.

**Update:**

added finally block to close the files.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class TestFile {

  static final int IN_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 8;
  static final int OUT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 *9; // make the out-buffer > in-buffer, i am lazy and don't want to check for overruns
  static final int MIN_READ_BYTES = 8;
  static final int MIN_WRITE_BYTES = 8;

  private File readFromFile1(File inFile) {

    final File outFile = new File("file2.txt");

    final ByteBuffer inBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(IN_BUFFER_SIZE);
    final ByteBuffer outBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(OUT_BUFFER_SIZE);

    FileChannel readChannel = null;
    FileChannel writeChannel = null;
    try {
      // open a file channel for reading and writing
      readChannel = FileChannel.open(inFile.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.READ);
      writeChannel = FileChannel.open(outFile.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);

      long totalReadByteCount = 0L;
      long totalWriteByteCount = 0L;

      boolean readMore = true;
      while (readMore) {

        // read some bytes into the in-buffer
        int readOp = 0;
        while ((readOp = readChannel.read(inBuffer)) != -1) {
          totalReadByteCount += readOp;
        } // while

        // prepare the in-buffer to be consumed
        inBuffer.flip();

        // check if there where errors
        if (readOp == -1) {
          // end of file reached, read no more
          readMore = false;
        } // if

        // now consume the in-buffer until there are at least MIN_READ_BYTES in the buffer
        while (inBuffer.remaining() >= MIN_READ_BYTES) {
          // add data to the write buffer
          outBuffer.putLong(someOperation(inBuffer));
        } // while

        // compact the in-buffer and prepare for the next read, if we need to read more.
        // that way the possible remaining bytes of the in-buffer can be consumed after leaving the loop
        if (readMore) inBuffer.compact();

        // prepare the out-buffer to be consumed
        outBuffer.flip();

        // write the out-buffer until the buffer is empty
        while (outBuffer.hasRemaining())
          totalWriteByteCount += writeChannel.write(outBuffer);

        // prepare the out-buffer for writing again
        outBuffer.flip();
      } // while

      // error handling
      if (inBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
        System.err.println("Truncated data! Not a long value! bytes remaining: " + inBuffer.remaining());
      } // if

      System.out.println("read total: " + totalReadByteCount + " bytes.");
      System.out.println("write total: " + totalWriteByteCount + " bytes.");

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Some error occurred while reading from File: " + e);
    } finally {
      if (readChannel != null) {
        try {
          readChannel.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("Could not close read channel: " + e);
        } // catch
      } // if

      if (writeChannel != null) {
        try {
          writeChannel.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("Could not close write channel: " + e);
        } // catch
      } // if
    } // finally

    return outFile;
  }

  private long someOperation(ByteBuffer bb) {
    // consume the buffer, do whatever you want with the buffer.
    return bb.getLong(); // consumes 8 bytes of the buffer.
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestFile testFile = new TestFile();
    File source = new File("input.txt");
    testFile.readFromFile1(source);
  }

}
```

Comment: That's a bloody complicated way to reimplement `java.io.BufferedInputStream`

Comment: Terrible code. There is a very simple 5-line way to write this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
private File readFromFile1(File file1) {

    int offset = 0;
    long message = 0;
    File file2 = null;

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);

        byte[] data = new byte[8]; //Read buffer
        byte[] tmpbuf = new byte[8]; //Temporary chunk buffer

        file2 = new File("file2.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file2.getAbsolutePath(), true);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

        int readcnt; //Read count
        int chunk; //Chunk size to write to tmpbuf

        while ((readcnt = fis.read(data, 0, 8)) != -1) {

            //// POINT A ////
            //Skip chunking system if an 8 byte octet is read directly.
            if(readcnt == 8 && offset == 0){
                message = someOperation(tmpbuf); // operation according to business logic
                dos.writeLong(message);
                continue;
            }

            //// POINT B ////
            chunk = Math.min(tmpbuf.length - offset, readcnt); //Determine how much to add to the temp buf.

            System.arraycopy(data, 0, tmpbuf, offset, chunk); //Copy bytes to temp buf

            offset = offset + chunk; //Sets the offset to temp buf

            if (offset == 8) {
                message = someOperation(tmpbuf); // operation according to business logic
                dos.writeLong(message);

                if (chunk < readcnt) {
                    System.arraycopy(data, chunk, tmpbuf, 0, readcnt - chunk);
                    offset = readcnt - chunk;
                } else {
                    offset = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        //// POINT C ////
        //Process remaining bytes here...
        //message = foo(tmpbuf);
        //dos.writeLong(message);

        fos.close();
        dos.close();
        fis.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Some error occurred while reading from File:" + e);
    }

    return file2;
}
```

In this excerpt of code, what I did was:

1. Modify your reading code to include the amount of bytes actually read from the read() method (noted readcnt).
2. Added a byte chunking system (the processing does not happen until there are at least 8 bytes in the chunking buffer).
3. Allowed for separate processing of the final bytes (that do not make up a 8 byte octet).

As you can see from the code, the data being read is first stored in a chunking buffer (denoted tmpbuf) until at least 8 bytes are available. This will happen only if 8 bytes are not always available (If 8 bytes are available directly and nothing is chunked, directly process. *See "Point A" in code*). This is done as a form of optimization to prevent excess array copies.

The chunking system uses offsets which increment every time bytes are written to tmpbuf until it reaches a value of 8 (it will not go over as the Math.min() method used in the assignment of 'chunk' will limit the value). Upon offset == 8, proceed to execute the processing code.

If that particular read produced more bytes than actually processed, continue writing them to tmpbuf, from the beginning again, whilst setting offset appropriately, otherwise set offset to 0.

Repeat cycle.

The code will leave the last few bytes of data that do not fit in an octet in the array tmpbuf with the offset variable indicating how much has actually been written. This data can then be processed separately at point C.

Seems a lot more complicating than it should be, and there probably is a better solution (possibly using existing java library methods), but off the top of my head, this is what I got. Hope this is clear enough for you to understand.